# how use UTL_FILE package for write file on map drive?

Tags: oracle, dictionary, directory, drive, utl-file

I use **UTL_FILE** package in my procedure for saving file on database server but i need to save file on another server for that i make a map drive but this UTL_FILE not saving files on my MAP Drive me also check manually drive Read and write the file but through procedure UTL_FILE not ABLE TO save the file on map drive and i got this error **"Data Base Error: ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536 ORA-29283: invalid file operation "**

Comment: if UTL_FILE not good for this please recommend  another package or function

Comment: Was this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a directory on a server that is not the **database server**, option that used to work for me was to use **UNC** (Universal Naming Convention) while creating directory (as an Oracle object). For example:

```
No : Z:\files_4005
Yes: \\my-another-server\d$\home\gis\files_4005"
```